# Change format of numbers without making number of class chr

Tags: r, format

In Spain the format for numbers is for example: 4.000.000,25 (4 million and 1/4). Is there a way to change the format of numbers (preferably for the whole R project) without it being changed to characters?

Right now I preform a function on all my dataframes. Function looks like:

```
fnx = function(x){print(formatC(x, format = "d", big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","), quote=F)}
fnx(567*4325)
# 2.452.275

class(fnx(567*4325))
# "character"
```

Is there another way? And a way to not transform it to a character class?

Comment: Does class matter in printing? Do your calculations before printing

Comment: @AnilGoyal good point! It doesn't. But I need to use it in a Rmarkdown while also using numeric functions like `max` in the text etc. Its very time consuming and ugly to convert it back and forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `comma` from [`formattable`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/formattable/versions/0.2.1/topics/comma)

```
out <- formattable::comma(567*4325, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
out
#[1] 2.452.275,00
```

-check the `class`

```
is.numeric(out)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Arun you never cease to amaze us.  :)